# PHP /MySQL dynamic breadcrumb

Tags: php, mysql

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id_category|parent_id|category_level|category_sort|category_name|category_rw_tag|
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|1          |0        |1             |NULL         |Shopping     |NULL           |
|2          |1        |2             |NULL         |Laptops      |NULL           |
|3          |2        |3             |NULL         |Accessories  |NULL           |
|4          |3        |4             |NULL         |HDD          |NULL           |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a table of categories. to the configuration shown above.
Fist of my problem :
I would like to build a breadcrumb like this :

```
Shopping > Laptops > Accesories > HDD
```

Second :
the breadcrumb. must be dynamic! 
so when I query the db table with parameter id_category= 5 
to display :

```
Shopping > Laptops > Accesories > HDD
```

when I query the db table with parameter id_category= 4

```
Shopping > Laptops > Accesories
```

...and so on.

I have read all question regarding my question but simply I had no idea how to d this.

Php Jedy's you are my only Hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would have to do some queries to retrieve each category until you hit a root category (i.e parent_id = 0). so in your example you would query category with id = 4, check the row parent_id is not equal to zero so query the next category with the parent_id and so on.

If your ecommerce website doesn't have too much categories that would be ok, if you have more than 5 levels of categories I would advice to make a breadscrumb field in your table with an already formated text.

Comment: Thank's.I just add one more column to store ascendants.Job done.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a logical duplicate of [What is the best practice for fetching a tree of nodes from a database for further rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258559/what-is-the-best-practice-for-fetching-a-tree-of-nodes-from-database-for-further).

There is a long list of articles and resources you can use.

Comment: Thank's.Too complex for my qualification. I just add one more column to store ascendants.Job done.